# Java Persistence Composite ID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, javax

I'm trying to insert a record with composite primary key, but at the time of saving a new record I get this message:

> e = (org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException)
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field
>   value [POST_INSERT_INDICATOR] value by reflection...

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "produto")
@IdClass(ProdutoId.class)
public class Produto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_produto")
    private Long idProduto;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "oficina", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long idOficina;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "oficina")
    private Oficina oficina;

}



@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
public class ProdutoId implements Serializable {

    public Long idProduto;
    public Long idOficina;

}


@Repository
public interface ProdutoRepository extends JpaRepository<Produto, ProdutoId> {}
```

Has anyone ever seen a bug like this?

Comment: could you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Yes:

e = (org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException) org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value [POST_INSERT_INDICATOR] value by reflection : [class com.example.persistence.ProdutoId.idProduto] setter of com.example.persistence.ProdutoId.idProduto; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [POST_INSERT_INDICATOR] value by reflection : [class com.example.persistence.ProdutoId.idProduto] setter of com.example.persistence.ProdutoId.idProduto

Comment: Why you marked idOficina  as insertable = false in your  @Column annotation? Are you sure, what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I did it just as a test, but even removing it, the same thing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create composite primary key you can refer this example,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="testuserrole")
public class UserRole{
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserRoleId id = new UserRoleId();

    public UserRoleId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UserRoleId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Transient
    public long getUserId() {
        return id.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        id.userId=userId;
    }

    @Transient
    public long getRoleId() {
        return id.roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(long roleId) {
        id.roleId=roleId;
    }

}

@Embeddable
class UserRoleId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    public long userId;

    @Column(name = "role_id")
    public long roleId;

}
```

Comment: With this code I get this return: Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.example.persistence.ProdutoId for property produtoId; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type java.lang.String to required type com.example.persistence.ProdutoId for property produtoId: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: Thanks Anil, I've solved the problem by using your example

Comment: Your welcome :-) If your problem resolved, please accept the answer